# ADODB character limit of 255 characters for Postgres data

Tags: vba, postgresql, adodb

I am using ADODB recordset to import some data from Postgres to Excel using VBA. I have one column where the number of characters exceed 255. Unfortunately, when pulling the data from Postgres, recordset gets populated only upto 255 characters for that column. Rest of the data is cut off. Is there anyway to overcome this limit? I have verified that there is no issue with the character limit for that column within Excel.

EDIT:
I cant share the code so here is an example of what my VBA code looks like:

```
Dim objConnection As Object
Dim objRecordset As Object
Dim sqlstring As String

ConStr= "Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE};Server=IP 
address;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"

sqlstring = 'SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC from tableA'

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRecordset.CursorLocation = 3

objConnection.Open ConStr

objRecordset.Open sqlstring, objConnection

For i = 0 To 2
    If objRecordset.Fields(i).Value <> " " Or 
    objRecordset.Fields(i).Value <> Null Or objRecordset.Fields(i).Value 
    <> "" Then
                ActiveCell.Value = objRecordset.Fields(i).Value
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    End If
Next i
```

In the above example, ColumnB is 1500 characters n length. But in Excel I see only 255 characters. The Recordset itself picks up only 255 characters. I am trying to overcome this limit.

Comment: Always helps to show your code...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added an example code to better explain the issue.

Comment: What is the field type for the data you're having a problem with?

Comment: @TimWilliams the datatype of the column was varchar in postgresql

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by editing the connection string. Followed the page: [odbc.postgresql.org/docs/config.html](https://odbc.postgresql.org/docs/config.html) and added "B0=5000" in the connection string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).